# What does it mean to be a daemon thread?

Tags: java

I'm fully aware of the impact of flagging a thread as a daemon thread on JVM exit (if all non-daemon threads exit, the JVM will exit.)

Are there other side-effects to setting a thread as a daemon?

(as a complete aside, which is really irrelevant except for semantics, is the meaning of a daemon thread not backwards in this case: shouldn't a daemon thread keep the JVM alive...for instance, if I wrote my own HTTP daemon and started it running, wouldn't I want the JVM to remain alive as long as that thread is alive?  Or is there some other semantic for the term 'daemon'?)

Comment: Typically you have daemon threads and non-daemon threads running at the same time: the non-daemon threads are doing useful work but the daemon threads are just sitting there waiting for stuff to happen. After the useful work is done, the program should exit; you don't want it held up by threads which are doing nothing. In your example, the HTTP daemon is a daemon *process*, not a daemon thread. One might imagine a desktop computer that shuts down when no non-daemon processes are running, and you wouldn't want a server keeping it on. (Or maybe you would... whatever, it's not the best name.)

Comment: Yeah - I understand the behavior perfectly well, and exploit it regularly.  My completely random aside was just a question to see if others agreed on the confusing-ness of the name :)

Comment: It's not really confusing, a daemon is expected to never exit--to always be running when the program is running, since they NEVER really exit, they shouldn't stop the program itself from exiting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have it, it means that the thread is detached and will run as long as the JVM runs, unless you stop it explicitly.  By spec, the JVM keeps running as long as any *non*-daemon thread is running.

Beyond that, it doesn't mean much of anything.

You could argue that this is backwards — after all, *shutdown(8)* kills the daemon processes — but the JVM should act like a well-behaved process otherwise, which means people should be able to expect it to terminate without having to be killed.  So this spec is a design decision based on what the more common use case will be.

Answer (score 3):

A daemon thread is a service to other threads.
Its only a daemon for the jvm itself not for the outside world. thus if only daemons excist they have no more use.
If you want an http daemon you just write an httpserver with normal threads and invoke it as a daemon using the toolset of your os to run apps as a daemon.

To conlcude a daemon thread in jvm is not a daemon thread for the os. Daemons are usually infinite loops and you dont want your jvm to go on infinitely while all you have running are a few daemons thats wait for input(which is not given).